# Test if docker memcached container is used

Tags: python, django, docker, memcached

I am using `memcached` for caching in django and both are in separate containers. Everything seems to be working well, however, how can I make sure that the new caching mechanism is being used?

I have read about a couple of approaches (`telnet`, `cache.set` and `cache.get` etc.), but I am not sure if they will yield an appropriate result, when both are in different docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

The [`stats` memcached command](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#statistics) will dump statistics for the server.

```
$ echo stats | nc <memcache_ip> 11211 | grep -e connections -e get_ -e cmd_
STAT max_connections 1024
STAT curr_connections 2
STAT total_connections 6
STAT rejected_connections 0
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT get_expired 0
STAT get_flushed 0
```

Run the command, use the django app for something that should be cached, run the command again and compare the numbers.

Comment: Well, if the container's IP is 0.0.0.0 and your solution is correct, my caching is not working, as only the `total_connections` is changing.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 would be correct if you map port 11211 from the host into the container.  or if you are running the above command inside the container.

Comment: The above command, I ran outside the container. Yet, even from inside the container, it makes no difference.